# How to show the only parent category product in listing page

Tags: magento

How can I show the only parent category product in the listing page,and also I need Is Anchor enabled so that my layer navigation work.

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS VERY BAD SOLUTION! DON'T TRY THIS AT HOME!!!

Answering on your question. The method you are looking for is here:

> Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection

```
public function addCategoryFilter(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category)
{
    $this->_productLimitationFilters['category_id'] = $category->getId();
    if ($category->getIsAnchor()) {
        unset($this->_productLimitationFilters['category_is_anchor']);
    } else {
        $this->_productLimitationFilters['category_is_anchor'] = 1;
    }

    if ($this->getStoreId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract::DEFAULT_STORE_ID) {
        $this->_applyZeroStoreProductLimitations();
    } else {
        $this->_applyProductLimitations();
    }

    return $this;
}
```

You need just to change `if ($category->getIsAnchor()) {` to `if (!($category->getIsAnchor())) {`

But don't forget that ***this fix can cause some problems***. For example calculation number of products inside some category.

**Better tell us, for what purpose do you need is_anchor property to be enabled?**